# TFS2015 do not see the project files, can not check in anything

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfvc

I'm new to TFS 2015.
I had a new repository created in TFS 2015 and added a branch *Dev*.
Then added the project files successfully and checked them all in.
Next I deleted the the content and the branch *Dev* in Source Control Explorer and committed the changes.
Next, created a new branch *Development*. Added the same project files to the local folder called *Development*.
Issue is in Source Control Explorer I do not see the files to add and check in. What am I missing or how to fix the issue?
It seems TFS thinks the files are already checked in although I deleted them when it was checked in Dev branch.

Comment: What is the version control type of your repository? Git or TFVC?
I tested on Git repository and TFVC repository, but did not reproduce the issue.
Could you please share more details and screenshots about how to reproduce the issue? Include what tools you use on your local, such as VS or VS Code.

When you check in (or push) new commits, make sure you have connected to the correct remote repository.

Comment: Hi @user10829672, I have not heard from you for a couple of days. Just want to say Hi and check if there is anything more I can help. Please Share more details about the problem so that we can investigate this problem further.

Comment: Hello Ben, I've resolved the issue. For some reason I did not get the + sign next to the files. Somehow, it magically appeared after some time. In between I was trying many things and not sure what triggered it. At the end I was able to check all code in. If I did find out what was the action that made it work I'll come back and post it. It may be helpful to some one else. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @user10829672, Glad that the problem has been solved. If you have any progress, please post an answer as the summary of the reason and the solution for the problem. As you mentioned, it may be helpful to the people who have the similar problems when they are looking for a solution. Thanks very much.